# retrive distinct values from group_concat in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a query like this : -

```
SELECT `stock`.`Stock_Id` AS `Stock_Id`,
       `product`.`Product_Id` AS `Product_Id`,
       `product`.`Product_Name` AS `Product_Name`,
       `product`.`Model_No` AS `Model_No`,
       `product`.`Product_Status` AS `Product_Status`,
       `prod_cat_ven`.`Category_Id` AS `Category_Id`,
       group_concat(`prod_cat_ven`.`Vendor_Id` separator ',') AS `Product_Vendor`,
       group_concat(`prod_cat_ven`.`Product_Vendor_Qty` separator ',') AS `Product_Vendor_Qty`,
       group_concat(`prod_cat_ven`.`Product_Purchase_Price` separator ',') AS `Product_Purchase_Price`,
       `stock`.`Closing_Quantity` AS `Closing_Qty`,
       `product`.`Is_Deleted` AS `Is_Deleted`
FROM ((`inksand`.`tbl_inksand_product` `product`
       JOIN `inksand`.`tbl_inksand_product_category_vendor` `prod_cat_ven` on((`product`.`Product_Id` = `prod_cat_ven`.`Product_Id`)))
      JOIN `inksand`.`vw_inksand_stock_max` `stock` on((`prod_cat_ven`.`Product_Id` = `stock`.`Product_Id`)))
GROUP BY `product`.`Product_Id`
```

I just want to show that

```
Vendor id - 27
Stock - 29
Quantity - 29   
Price - 1080
```

the latest inserted row in price, and distinct vendor wise with quantity.

How to achieve this.

Comment: Please add line breaks to your query. It will be much easier to read for everyone, including yourself. Your question itself: `group_concat` is an aggregate function. If you don't want to aggregate, don't use it.

Comment: incidentally, all those parenthesis in the from clause are unnecessary, and detract from the readability.  also instead of showing us just a query, perhaps show us the results of that query, and how they differ from what you want. sample data is also beneficial

Comment: Can you put you tables structure ? use this http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/